# iPad: upload photos to web storage (Flickr or Picasa)

Tags: ipad, photos, storage

I want to upload photos from iPad to web storage.

I use Google Plus and Dropbox.

But these things have some disadvanteges like:

- Dropbox have a limited space
- Google Plus doesn't upload a full size photos (but theirs resolutions are pretty good, really)

Now I want to try Picasa or Flickr as alternative and specific web services for photos.

Which app can upload photos on Flickr or Picasa as Google Plus and Dropbox best parts do:
 - Dropbox download full-size photos
 - Google Plus automate upload them via wifi, without connection to laptop

Or maybe I miss something? Maybe there is a more clean iDifferent way?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using Everpix? I've fairly recently started using it to keep a full back up of all my pictures, even the ones I don't want to share through sites like Flickr.

There is an online service, along with iOS apps, take a look at https://www.everpix.com

Comment: good, but does this service have an ability 'automate upload photos'?

Comment: Yes, the iPhone and iPad app have a background upload process that uploads the latest pictures on the camera roll. If you've got concerns over data usage you can set that to only upload when on Wi-Fi, or there is a desktop app that will upload new pictures when you plug your iPhone or iPad into the computer.